# In Oracle, if I make a composite index on 2 columns, then in which situation this index will be used to search the record?

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing

In Oracle, if I make a composite index on 2 columns, then in which situation this index will be used to search the record ?

a) If my query has a WHERE clause which involves first column 
e.g. WHERE first_column = 'John'

b) If my query has a WHERE clause which involves second column
e.g. WHERE second_column = 'Sharma'

c) Either a or b

d) Both a and b

e) Not specifically these 2 columns but it could be any column in the WHERE clause.

f) Only column a or both columns a and b

Comment: Not able to understand the language

Comment: Kindly answer in English

Comment: Sorry. Here it is: http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/the-equals-operator/concatenated-keys

Comment: After reading the article, I found that in case of composite index, a condition on only second column can't be used in the WHERE clause to search using the index. Either condition should be on first column of the composite columns or both the columns. But according to the reference given by @John Heller even in case of second column, Oracle performs "index skip scan" that is taking the advantage of index. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**d) Both a or b**

If the leading column is used, Oracle will likely use a regular index range scan and just ignore the unused columns.

If a non-leading column is used, Oracle can use an [index skip scan](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/TGSQL/tgsql_optop.htm#TGSQL238).  In practice a skip scan is not used very often.

---

There are two completely different questions here: when *can* Oracle use an index and when *will* Oracle use an index.  The above explains that Oracle *can* use an index in either case, and you can test that out with a hint: `/*+ index(table_name index_name) */`.

Determining when Oracle *will* use an index is much trickier.  Oracle uses multi-block reads for full table scans and fast full index scans, and uses single-block reads for other index scans.  This means a full table scan is more efficient when reading a larger percent of the data.  But there are a lot of factors involved: the percentage of data, how big is the index, system statistics that tell Oracle how fast single- and multi-block IO are, the number of distinct values (especially important for choosing a skip scan), index clustering factor (how ordered is the table by the index columns), etc.

Comment: I made a composite unique index on empid and empname. I tried different prediactes with WHERE clause in the query. What I found from the execution plan is that whenever I give the condition on both the columns, only then the INDEX is used, and if I make a non-unique index, the index is not used even if I give a condition on both the columns. Kindly explain.

Answer (score 3):

I happen to think that MySQL does a pretty good job of describing how composite indexes are used.  The documentation is [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html).

The basic idea is that the index would normally be used in the following circumstances:

- When the `where` condition is an equality on `col1` (`col1 = value`).
- When the `where` condition is an inequality or `in` on `col1` (`col1 in (list)`, `col1 < value`)
- When the `where` condition is an equality on `col1` and `col2`, connected by an `and` (`col1 = val1 and col2 = val2`)
- When the `where` condition is an equality on `col1` and an inequality or `in` on `col2`.
- Any of the above four cases where additional columns are used with additional conditions on other columns, connected by an `and`.

In addition, the index would normally be used if `col1` and `col2` are the only columns referenced in the query.  This is called a covering index, and -- assuming there are other columns in the table -- it is faster to read the index than the original table because the index is smaller.

Oracle has a pretty smart optimizer, so it might also use the index in some related circumstances, for instance when `col1` uses an `in` condition along with a condition on `col2`.

In general, a condition will not qualify for an index if the column is an argument to a function.  So, these clauses would not use a basic index:

```
where month(col1) = 3
where trunc(col1) = trunc(sysdate)
where abs(col1) < 1
```

Oracle supports functional indexes, so if these constructs are actually important, you can create an index on `month(col1)`, `trunc(col1)`, or `abs(col1)`.

Also, `or` tends to make the use of indexes less likely.

Answer (score 0):

The optimizer will use indexes in several scenarios. Even if not "perfect".

Optimaly, if you are querying using the first columns in the index, then the index will be used.  Even if you're referencing only the first column, then it will still use the index if the optimizer deems it filters out enough data.
If the indexed columns aren't answering the query requirement (for instance only referencing the second column in the where clause), the optimizer could still use the index for a full (table) index scan, if it holds all of the data required, because the index is smaller than the full table.

In your example, if you are only querying from that table, and you only have that one index, (a) will use the index,  (b) will use it if you are only querying columns in the index, while the table itself has more.

If you have other indexes, or join other tables, then that could affect the explain plan compeltely.

Check out http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/indexes.htm